# Angular 2 Route Aliases

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have two routes, one goes to a list of blogs and the other to an individual blog. Here are the routes.

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'blogs',
    component: 'BlogListComponent,
  }
  {
    path: 'blogs/:id',
    component: 'BlogComponent,
  }
];
```

I would like to have an alias for my `blogs/:id` so `blogs/231` shows in the address bar as `blogs/blog-title-goes-here`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using the post ID in the URL, you should assign a (unique) slug to each entry, include that slug in the URL (instead of the ID) and also find/identify the requested post via the slug.

For creating the slug, you can use 3rd-party-code such as https://www.npmjs.com/package/slug.

Comment: The url does not explain anything about slugs in the url Or I missed it ?

Comment: Based on the example from the original post: instead of resolving `231` as a blog post ID, the slug `blog-title-goes-here` (which, of course, must previously have been saved as a unqiue property of the blog post with ID 123) should be resolved and hence find blog post 123.